# Exclude one document from mongo db result

Tags: mongodb

How can one document be excluded from mongo db result?

For eg:

```
{
   "_id":ObjectId("57bc115edb04d82550e823cb"),
   "menu":[ ],
   "properties":[
      {
         "name":"N1",
         "value":"17"
      },
      {
         "name":"N2",
         "value":"10"
      },
      {
         "name":"N3",
         "value":"14"
      }
   ]
```

}

How to get result with properties having name N1 & N2 but not N3?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/ne/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get document without having name is N3 of properties use [$ne](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/ne/#ne) (*not equal*) operator

```
db.collectionName.find( { "properties.name": { $ne: "N3" } } )
```

**Updated:**

You need to use aggregate query to get all record with properties only discard properties element that contains N3 as name.

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {$unwind:"$properties"},
    {$match:{"properties.name":{$ne:"N3"}}},
    {$group:{
        _id:"$_id",
         properties:{$push:"$properties"},
         menu: {$first:"$menu"}
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: update seems shocking.And I get empty result if replace update by find.

Comment: where executed your query mongo shell or else where ? @KamalK

Comment: should be work and get result if `properties` array does not contains `name:"N3"`

Comment: empty result if properties array contains name:"N3"

Comment: isn't it your expected result?

Comment: No Expected result with properties having name N1 & N2 but not N3

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/ne/) operator. You should be able to formulate a query using this keyword.